# ISNULL(Sum(Case When ) returning the null instead of sum

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to have a column return the sum of a weeks worth of hours from a time unit column. However, It's only returning a null value, and I'm not certain why. Could anyone help? Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT
[Employee Name],

[Week1] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tdate BETWEEN DATEADD(Week,-3,Timesheetdate) AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(WEEK,-2,Timesheetdate))   THEN (Units) END),0 )

[Week2] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tdate BETWEEN DATEADD(Week,-2,Timesheetdate) AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(WEEK,-1,Timesheetdate))   THEN (Units) END),0 )

From #Temp
LEFT JOIN TransTable ON TranTable.trankey = Timesheet.tkey

Group By 
EmployeeName,
tdate,
tunits,
timesheetdate
```

Comment: Are you calling this from a program or from management studio or equivalent?

Comment: just group by  the `[Employee Name]` column and see if that make nulls go away

Comment: @M.Ali: explain why that would make a difference.

Comment: I'm calling it through Management Studio in an SP to later be used in SSRS.

Thank you for looking at it!

Comment: If you could add some sample data, it would be really helpful

Comment: To be clear, are you getting a result set with the employee name but null week 1 or 2 values, or are you getting no results at all?

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload sample data on here... Are you requesting the result I'm getting or is there a place for me to upload a database to?

and I'm getting no results at all..

In other news though... I gave up on that logic last night and declared my Timesheetdate, then rewrote it using - where tdate< dateadd(week,-1,@timesheetdate1) and tdate > dateadd(week,-2,@timesheetdate1)  etc. and finally got it to work returning the values I needed. Thank you everyone for looking through it. I'm not sure why it didn't like the initial query though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE #Temp
CREATE TABLE #Temp ( [EmployeeName] varchar(100),  Timesheetdate datetime , Units int , tdate datetime)


insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-02',1,'2015-03-02')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',2,'2015-02-02')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',3,'2015-02-02')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-27',4,'2015-02-02')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-24',5,'2015-02-02')

insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-02',1,'2015-02-15')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',2,'2015-02-17')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',3,'2015-02-18')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-27',4,'2015-02-20')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-24',5,'2015-02-14')

insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-02',1,'2015-02-28')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',2,'2015-02-27')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',3,'2015-02-26')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-27',4,'2015-02-25')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-24',5,'2015-02-24')

insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-02',1,'2015-02-21')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',2,'2015-02-20')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-02',3,'2015-02-18')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-02-27',4,'2015-02-20')
insert into #Temp values ( 1, '2015-03-24',5,'2015-02-18')


SELECT
EmployeeName,
[Week1] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tdate BETWEEN DATEADD(Week,-3,Timesheetdate) AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(WEEK,-2,Timesheetdate))   THEN (Units) ELSE 0 END),0 ),

[Week2] = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN tdate BETWEEN DATEADD(Week,-2,Timesheetdate) AND DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(WEEK,-1,Timesheetdate))   THEN (Units) ELSE 0 END),0 )

From #Temp
GROUP BY EmployeeName
```

It seems to work just fine, all I did I've added ELSE 0 ( which was not necesary as it works just fine without it too).

Take a better look at your dates. Maybe it should return null